# Using useSortableData based on useMemo() after data update in React app

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-usememo

I've made application based on this example

https://codesandbox.io/embed/table-sorting-example-ur2z9?fontsize=14&hidenavigation=1&theme=dark

But also I need data update in table (adding, removing)

I use

```
const { items, requestSort, sortConfig } = useSortableData(data.items, sortObj);
const [datarows, setDatarows] = useState({})

useEffect(() => {
setDatarows(items)
});

const updateData = (row, useropt) => {
...
/* here fetching some data */
...
setDatarows(rows2);
}
```

But after data update useSortableData function is sorting initially added data
How to make useSortableData use updated data?

I've tried

```
const [datarows, setDatarows] = useState(data.items)
const { items, requestSort, sortConfig } = useSortableData(datarows, sortObj);
```

But in this case I get

**Unhandled Runtime Error**

TypeError: Invalid attempt to spread non-iterable instance.
In order to be iterable, non-array objects must have a Symbol.iterator method.

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Looking at the code you provided it looks like useSortableData is has items as a dependency in the useMemo of the sortedItems. Meaning that any changes to data.items will result in a recalculation of the sorted items.

You have not provided the piece of code from where you get data.items, therefore this is the extent of what I can help with

[image]

Comment: `function DataTable(props) {
    const data = props.content` - just coming array of data from backend. So data.items are not changing. But changing `items` which is returning after useSortableData

Comment: when should the items be re-sorted?

Comment: when clicking on cell in table head: `onClick={() => requestSort('name')}`. But after table loaded - table data can be changed (can be added/removed rows). Now function useSortableData is using initial data, loaded at very beginning... I understand, why: `const { items, requestSort, sortConfig } = useSortableData(data.items, sortObj);` - but how to sort the re-rendered table?

Answer (score 0):

Solved.

Data loading and changing left in main Component.
The table and sorting
`const { items, requestSort, sortConfig } = useSortableData(data.items, sortObj);`
moved to other component